# DropDownList not autosized properly within Jquery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, html.dropdownlistfor

My dropdownlist width is smaller than the longest text in the SelectList.  When I click the dropdown, it resizes to fit properly.  If I remove the .accordion from the div, the dropdowns all size correctly when the page loads.  How can I get it to size properly?  This is how I set the accordion.

```
            $("#acc").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true
            });
```

One of my dropdowns:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Contract.contract_type) %>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Contract.contract_type, new SelectList(Model.Lookups.nfoContractTypes, "id", "contract_type", Model.Contract.contract_type), new { @class = "edittext" })%>
```

In my .css:

```
fieldset .edittext
{
    float:right;
}
```

Without accordion:
[image]

With accordion:
[image]

After clicking:
[image]

*EDIT*
Just discovered, it is properly sized in Firefox, but not in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by commenting out the custom css for the ui-widget so that it would use my css file.

```
/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
/* .ui-widget { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: .8em } */
```